# Attribute defined test data with Nunit, AutoFixture, NSubstitute and AutoSubstituteDataAttribute

Tags: c#, testing, nunit, autofixture, nsubstitute

I like the option to define tests using attributes. However, I must be doing something wrong. I have installed the packages:

```
<packages>
  <package id="AutoFixture" version="3.46.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="AutoFixture.AutoNSubstitute" version="3.46.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="AutoFixture.NUnit3" version="3.46.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="NSubstitute" version="1.10.0.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="NUnit" version="3.2.1" targetFramework="net451" />
</packages>
```

Single substituted parameters go through:

```
[Theory, AutoSubstituteData]
public void Test_Single([Substitute] Service svc)
{
     // executed, shown as success
}
```

While mixing substitution and some other values fails:

```
[Theory, AutoSubstituteData]
public void Test_Mixed(int version, string name, [Substitute] IService svc)
{
     // not executed, shown as inconclusive
}
```

The attribute:

```
public class AutoSubstituteDataAttribute : Ploeh.AutoFixture.NUnit3.AutoDataAttribute
{
    public AutoSubstituteDataAttribute()
        : base(new Fixture().Customize(new AutoConfiguredNSubstituteCustomization()))
    {
    }
}
```

The test output says:

> NUnit Adapter 3.0.10.0: Test execution complete
>
> Test adapter sent back a result for an unknown test case. Ignoring result for 'Test_Mixed(150,"name04f0cd50-e89f-4a8f-db6-dab69b58e98e",Castle.Proxies.IServiceProxy)'.

How do I get this to work in VS2015 or in general with NUnit 3x?

Comment: Is is possible for you to use xUnit [v2] ? You'll find stuff pretty much just works (and/or common messages can be googled etc.)

Comment: @RubenBartelink , I have installed xunit now including xunit.runner.visualstudio version 2.1.0, restarted VS, recompiled. The XUnit tests I added did not appear in test explorer. Tried to install xunit.runners, but it says there is no support for net451. That doesn't sound much like "just works". I'd rather fix this with NUnit, version 3 is a pretty decent test framework.

Comment: Sorry, I have to ruin but if you google why is the xunit runner not finding my tests, there are troubleshooting questions (one is mine) - And apologies for overstating - yes there can stilkl be problems. However one thing I can say is the bulk of people using AF with attributes are using xUnit.

Comment: @RubenBartelink, after a bit of fiddling with package versions I figured the class was not marked public (not required in nunit). XUnit test now appears and if it wasn't for the initial confusion, "it just works" in green... The only differences from the NUnit test are: Xunit.Theory and Ploeh.AutoFixture.XUnit2.AutoDataAttribute. I would still like to work with NUnit though. Thanks for your help anyways.

Comment: Glad you got sorted; stackoverflow.com/questions/16214684/why-is-the-xunit-runner-not-finding-my-tests/16214704#16214704 :P

Comment: Not quite sorted, but well narrowed down. Cheers.

Comment: While I can reproduce this issue, it looks like it's an issue with the NUnit 3 Visual Studio Test Adapter. If I run these tests with the NUnit 3 command-line runner, they both run and pass. May I suggest that you raise an issue for the NUnit 3 Visual Studio Test Adapter?

Comment: @MarkSeemann, thanks. It is possibly already in the pipeline for other bug: https://github.com/nunit/nunit3-vs-adapter/issues/97 - symptoms and description is quite similar, what do you think?

Comment: @RobertCutajar-Robajz I agree that it may be the same issue, and I can also see that you've posted there, which I think is a good idea :)

Comment: If you say it's a bug, it would be an acceptable answer, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

(From comments:)

This looks like an issue with the NUnit 3 Visual Studio Test Adapter. If I run these tests with the NUnit 3 command-line runner, they both run and pass.